# Controlling number of channels in weight/kernel in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

To implement a specific function, I need "input_channels" number of kernels in my layer, each having only a single channel depth, and not depth = "input_channels".
I need to convolve one kernel with one channel of the input, thus the output of the layer would have "input_channels" number of kernels.

Which python/numpy/tensorflow convolution function can allow such a convolution where the number of channels in kernel must not always be equal to "input_channels" and can be 1 instead?

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: Diagram for reference]

(if anyone wishes to know what all i have tried yet,

In the conv2d function of tensorflow, if I specify number of kernels = 1 to do this, then it will sum over all input_channels and number of output_channels will be 1, since it always initialises kernel depth = "input_channels".

Another option is to specify number of number of kernels = input_channels in conv2d function but this would create "input_channels" number of kernels of depth "input_channels", thus adding lot of complexity and incorrect implementation of my layer.

Yet another thing I tried was to initialise a kernel of volume (kernel_height, kernel_width, input_channels) and loop over the third dimension to convolve only a single input channel with a single kernel. But the tensorflow conv2d function requires a rank 4 kernel to work and gives the following error -

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'generic_act_func_4/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,28,28], [28,28]. )
```

Comment: I suspect you are looking for the Conv1D layer. It applies the convolution over only 1 dimension

Comment: But this function requires a 1-d convolution window, whereas my filters are all 2-d. I need to perform 2-d convolution between a grayscale/single-channeled filter and a single channel of the input.

Comment: I find it very difficult to follow your question. Descriptions/example of the data and code you've implemented would help a lot

Comment: Please refer to an image added for further elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you're trying to learn a separate model for each dimension in the input. Thus you will need 2D convolution filters with a filter depth of 1.

I believe there should be an easier way, but most logical to me would be to create a model consisting of a number of submodels equal to the depth of your input (32). Thus 32 models containing a single convolutional filter, receiving only one dimension of your input. Stacking the output from all models would then give the results as you require.

Another solution which would be interesting (but I'm not sure whether it will work, have not tried it myself) would be to do separable convolutions on the input.

A link to an article describing these operations:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-basic-introduction-to-separable-convolutions-b99ec3102728

You essentially want to perform only the 1st part of the separable convolution operation, which is exactly what the DepthwiseConv2D layer in keras/tensorflow does. So I would have a look at that if I where you. Would be interested to know whether this works out for you!